# Mocha Mock Carries To Another Test

Tags: ruby, functional-testing, ruby-mocha

I have been following the [15 TDD steps to create a Rails application](http://andrzejonsoftware.blogspot.com/2007/05/15-tdd-steps-to-create-rails.html) guide - but have run into an issue I cannot seem to resolve.  For the functional test of the WordsController, I have the following code:

```
class WordsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  
  test "should get learn" do
    get 'learn'
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "learn passes a random word" do    
    some_word = Word.new
    Word.expects(:random).returns(some_word)
    get 'learn'
    assert_equal some_word, assigns('word')
  end
end
```

In the Word class I have the following code:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.random
    all = Word.find :all
    all[rand(all.size)]
  end
end
```

When I run the tests, I experience the following error (shortened for brevity):

```
1) Failure: unexpected invocation: Word(...).random() satisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, already invoked once: Word(...).random()
```

I have tried changing changing the order of the tests along with a multitude of other things, but time and time again I continue to receive the same test failure - that Word.random() has already been invoked.

I'm running Rails 3.0 beta 4 and Mocha 0.9.8. I've searched long and hard for a solution to my problem, but I can't seem to find it.  I'm new to Ruby/Rails so am rather unfamiliar with the language and the frameworks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, mocked functionality was not isolated to a test, it seems to be a problem with the load order of Mocha.

I had some issues getting Mocha to work with Rails3. I found a few stackoverflow posts regarding, but didn't stumble across the solution until I found a post on agoragames.com

Basically, in the Gemfile of your project, the require for Mocha should look like:

```
gem 'mocha', :require => false
```

Then in `test/test_helper.rb`, add a require line for mocha:

```
...
...
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'mocha'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
...
...
```

I think the require line for mocha in the Gemfile means that you need to already have mocha installed as a gem, bundler won't take care of it for you.

Answer (score 20):

mocha needs to be loaded last. I struggled a lot with this problem too.

```
#Gemfile
  group :test
    gem 'mocha', '~>0.9.8', :require => false
    ...
  end
```

and

```
test_helper.rb
  ....
  #at the very bottom
  require 'mocha'
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed too. I was tearing my hair out with this for hours! Thanks! :)

Comment: +1, with migration to bundler i'v messed order of mocha loading

Comment: I use Sinatra where should I include that? spec_helper.rb? but I still have that problem.

Comment: As a newbie in Ruby/Rails coming from Java/Python, I struggled for the last hour with this one - had to debug for some time until I understood that mocha's test verify was only called if something from the mock was called (because the automatic call from the end requires the late binding), THANKS, THANKS, THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

How are you requiring mocha? Are you using bundler? It sounds a bit as if the mocha teardown hook isn't being called?

Comment: Is teardown supposed to be called between tests?

Comment: If `Mocha` has been loaded correctly, it will have monkey-patched the test framework to call `Mocha::API#mocha_verify` & `Mocha::API#mocha_teardown` i.e. you shouldn't need to explicitly call them. The reason I was asking how `Mocha` was being required, was to work out whether things are being loaded in the correct order, so that the monkey-patching works correctly.

Comment: If you set `MOCHA_OPTIONS=debug` as an environment variable when you run your tests, you will see which test frameworks are being successfully monkey-patched. If you are still having problems with this, let me know what the debug output is and tell me what version of Mocha you are using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, it seems mocha_teardown is not being called with rails31. Mocks that are setup are never removed... (this additional hack fixes it)

```
  class ActiveSupport::TestCase
    def teardown
      super
      Mocha::Mockery.instance.teardown
      Mocha::Mockery.reset_instance    
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Those solutions didn't work for me on their own, using Ruby 2.2.2, Rails 4.2.2, mocha 1.1.0, shoulda-context 1.2.1, factory_girl_rails 4.5.0 and a few more testing related gems.

What did it was **also** moving these two lines at the bottom of my `test_helper.rb`:

```
require 'mocha/setup'
require 'mocha/test_unit'
```

I also removed `require 'test/unit'`. It appears that `mocha/test_unit` already does that for me.