# Mocha not mocking a class method in a functional test (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocha.js

In a rails 3 app, I'm using mocha to do some mocking in my functional tests. However it doesn't seem to  mock a class method in the functional controller.

Controller code

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    response = User.tags_starting_with(params[:query])
    respond_with response
  end
end
```

Functional test

```
class TagsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  context "index action with query" do
    setup do
      query = "A_QUERY"
       get :index, :query => query, :format => "json"
       @tags = ["these", "are", "test", "tags"]
       User.expects(:tags_starting_with).returns(@tags).once
     end

    should "return JSON formatted tags array" do
      tags = JSON::parse @response.body
      assert_equal @tags, tags
    end
  end
end
```

Gemfile

```
gem "mocha"
```

If I run this test, I keep running into

```
- expected exactly once, not yet invoked: User.tags_starting_with(any_parameters)
```

If I use `rails console test` I can mock a class method just fine, and it works as expected.

I've been through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118866/mocha-mock-carries-to-another-test) and have done the Gemfile, `require "false"` bit. But to no avail, it just doesn't want to mock the class method of the `User` in the controller.

Other things I've tried, if I do `User.tags_starting_with("bla")` in the test itself, the expectation passes.

So any ideas on why the `User` in the controller isn't being mocked correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said on Twitter:
You're setting you your mock after you're doing your request :-)

Comment: And there I was mocking about with load paths, gemfile juggling. Thanks!