# Mocha: Silence satisfied expectations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mocha.js

Very often when I have a missed expectation in a unit test using mocha, it spits out dozens or hundreds of "satisfied expectations" that I really don't care about.  There's so much of it that I have to redirect testing output to a temp file, which is really annoying.

I am using Rails 2.3 and Mocha 0.10.0.

To clarify, I have the same issue as in
[Mocha Mock Carries To Another Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118866/mocha-mock-carries-to-another-test/4375296#4375296)
, and the solution there has not worked for me.  However, even if I can get that resolved, I would like to suppress "satisfied expectations".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could monkey patch mocha to achieve this. There's a method on `Mocha::Mockery` that returns the satisfied expectations which you could patch to return an empty array:

```
module Mocha
  class Mockery
    def satisfied_expectations
      []
    end
  end
end
```

If you put this in `test_helper.rb` it'll get picked up.

Alternatively for a bit more flexibility you could opt to only hide them when an environment variable is set:

```
module Mocha
  class Mockery
    def satisfied_expectations_with_optional
      if ENV['MOCHA_HIDE_SATISFIED']
        []
      else
        satisfied_expectations_without_optional
      end
    end
    alias_method_chain :satisfied_expectations, :optional
  end
end
```

Then run your tests like this:

```
> MOCHA_HIDE_SATISFIED=1 rake test
```